# print from ascx code behind - no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a webpart that I am trying and I am trying to print a gridview. I have a ascx.cs with one public class for code behind. I created a method to print the grid here :

```
        protected void print_grid_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fill_grid_search();
            grd_search.AllowPaging = false;
            grd_search.DataBind();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            grd_search.RenderControl(hw);
            string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
                .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
            sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
            sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
            sb.Append(gridHTML);
            sb.Append("\");");
            sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
            sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
            sb.Append("printWin.print();");
            sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
            fill_grid_search();
            grd_search.AllowPaging = true;

            grd_search.DataBind();
        }
```

Then I used this snippet of code to check for the form tag :

```
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            return; /*Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }
```

Then I get " no suitable method found to override. " from the debugger. Is there a way to do this without creating a partial class just for this one button event?

Comment: what class is your control inheriting from?

Comment: I think that is the problem. There is just one class for all the code behind.

Comment: A code-behind can only have one class. At the top of the file, where you define the class, there should be something like `public class WebControlName : XXXXXXX`. What is after the colon? What is the `XXXXXXX`?

Comment: System.Web.UI.UserControl